# Page for all items with a catalog price rule active

Tags: category-products, catalog-price-rules

I have 5 catalog price rules that affects 3-4 categories each, they are applied one each day of the week (say: on monday we have cat 3 and 6 on sale, on tuesday it's cat 5, on wednesday it's 7, 10, 11...) on my catalog and I want to have a "SALE" page that will show all items with said discount. I've searched and found not many options for this.

I was thinking maybe I want to create a dynamic category using firegento (https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory/blob/develop/README.md) but I'm not sure what attribute/values should it look for that affect the price rules? I'd like to avoid having to create a template for this manually, hence why I'm looking into the category option, as it would maintain the look and feel of the website with it's layered navigation and all

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this what you need, but I can recommend you this free extension: https://github.com/tzyganu/rule-products
This extension allows you to create separate product lists based on rules (with filters, sorting and everything a category has), kind of similar to the extension you mentioned, with the difference that you don't need to create categories.
But one additional thing it does, is to add a button on the catalog rule edit page that will allow you to clone the catalog rule to a list of products.

[image]

This way when you change something to a rule you don't need to replicate everything on a different screen to make your product list. You can click the button and it creates the list automatically.

Comment: Mmmh, could work but the extension hasn't seen an update in 3 years, that's a bit scary

Comment: Now that I see it, firegento hasn't seen one in 2, so I might as well try it on local and see if it serves the purpose

Comment: The extension wasn't updated in 3 years because it works :). And yeah, you can give it a try. It doesn't cost you anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not just filter by Product Category? Or better yet, add a new attribute to the relevant attribute set for something like "promo_day", with a value of M-F for example**, and then in the Product Grid in the admin, bulk assign all of the products in the relevant category, save, and repeat until you've bulk assigned your products to a specific "promo_day" attribute.

Next, setup catalog price rules and/or shopping cart price rules based on that product attribute corresponding to a particular day of the week for each of your products. Here's a great extension to make that process a bit simpler: https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html#screenshots

Tons of relevant features with **Special Promotions for Magento 2 by Amasty** that could solve help achieve your goal, possibly combined with a few other config options from additional modules.

[image: Using advanced promo conditions, including rules based on specific days and/or Customer Groups]
Lastly for the "Sale" page, you can use Magento's Categories and Subcategories to depending on which theme you have configured currently. Happy to help more if it earns me the bounty here :)

Comment: I am using 1.9 so that is a no go. Attributes is a hell of a job now, since I have quite so many products, and some have multiple categories so would be in more than one promo day